# Best practice for upgrading MySQL on a master-master setup

Tags: mysql, replication, mariadb, upgrade

Anyone have experience upgrading a master-master setup of MySQL 5.1 to a release version of MySQL while trying to keep at least one server online (in my case we are upgrading to MariaDB 5.5).

Comment: Did you do the upgrade? What process did you use?